# Input a data file .txt and output specific data to a new .txt file using Python

Tags: python

I would like to input or read the following data of a .txt file:

```
VIBRATION/SHOCK CALIBRATION DATA
DATE: 2/26/2012 
TIME: 0800
Time (ms)   Channel 1    Channel 2     Channel 3
0.0         -0.9         9.0           12.9
50.0        5.0          12            343  
100.0       56.7         120           0.8
150.0       90.0         0.9           12.0
200.0       32.9         12.4          34.0
```

Then output to a new .txt file such that only the numbers are written for Time and Channel 3 columns:

```
0.0     12.9
50.0    343
100.0   0.8
150.0   12.0
200.0   34.0
```

Comment: I have used a counter to only read below Time then output to a file but don't know the command to extract only Channel 3.

Answer (score 3):

As a complete example, consider something like the code below. I've added excessive comments to explain what each step is doing.

```
# Open the input file read-only...
with open('infile.txt', 'r') as infile:
    # Skip the first 4 lines, and store them as "header" in case we need them...
    # It's important that we use "next" here and _not_ infile.readline().
    # readline and the file iteration methods ("for line in file") can't be mixed
    header = [next(infile) for dummy in range(4)]

    # Open the output file, overwriting whatever is there...
    with open('outfile.txt', 'w') as outfile:
        # Loop over the lines in the input file
        for line in infile:
            # Strip off leading and trailing whitespace (e.g "\n") and 
            # split on whitespace. This gives us a list of strings.
            columns = line.strip().split()
            # Write the 1st and 4th columns in each row as left-justified 
            # columns with a fixed-width of 8
            outfile.write('{:8}{:8}\n'.format(columns[0], columns[3]))
```

If you're using an old version of python and wanted to avoid the `with` statements, you could write it like this:

```
# Open the input file read-only...
infile = open('infile.txt', 'r')
# Open the output file, overwriting whatever is there...
outfile = open('outfile.txt', 'w')

# Skip the first 4 lines, and store them as "header" in case we need them...
# It's important that we use "next" here and _not_ infile.readline().
# readline and the file iteration methods ("for line in file") can't be mixed
header = [next(infile) for dummy in range(4)]

# Loop over the lines in the input file
for line in infile:
    # Strip off leading and trailing whitespace (e.g "\n") and 
    # split on whitespace. This gives us a list of strings.
    columns = line.strip().split()
    # Write the 1st and 4th columns in each row as left-justified 
    # columns with a fixed-width of 8
    outfile.write('{:8}{:8}\n'.format(columns[0], columns[3]))

# Close the file objects once we're through with them..
# Python would close these automatically when the process ends, but it's a good
# idea to get in the habit of explicitly closing them once you don't need them.
# Otherwise, when you start writing code for longer-running processes, you'll 
# inadvertently leave lots of file handles laying around
infile.close()
outfile.close()
```

However, it's a good idea to get into the habit of using `with` statements to handle file objects. They ensure that file handles will be closed automatically even if there's an error in your code.  `with` statements are "context managers". They're very handy for a lot of things that would otherwise require "boilerplate" cleanup and/or entry code.

Comment: I'd add that you should be using the `rb` and `wb` (read and write binary, respectively), as it will have fewer cross-platform issues than the default `r` and `w` modes.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  Makes much more sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can call split() on the line string to get the columns:

```
t, ch1, ch2, ch3 = line.split()
```

The values returned will be strings. If you want numbers, use float() to convert them:

```
t_f = float(t)
ch3_f = float(ch3)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really a python guy but building on your comment above, once you've read down to the data you should be able to use `str.split()` on each line to get the values of the columns in that line.

Documentation here: http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.3/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods